# How to increase the grid resolution in character recognition in matlab neural network

Tags: matlab

I know that to create an input vector namely Alphabet, we use `prprob` function in Matlab that gives alphabet 35 rows with 26 columns, Each target vector is a 26-element vector with one in the position of the letter it represents and 0's everywhere else.

```
 [alphabet, targets] = prprob;
 i=1;
 ti=alphabet(:,i);
 letter{i}=reshape(ti, 5, 7)'; 
 letter{i}
 аns =
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 1 0 
 0 1 0 1 0 
 1 0 0 0 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 0 0 0 1 
 1 0 0 0 1
```

I want to increase the resolution of the input vector to a 10 by 14 grid because a higher accuracy is needed but I don't know how to go about doing this. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you'll type `edit prprob` in the command window, you'll see that the alphabet is 'hard-coded' in this script, so increasing the resolution would need to include some 2D interpolation of this small bitmaps.

Comment: @EBH so I can manually edit it from there?

Comment: I think the best option is to create a copy of this file and edit it as you wish.

Comment: @EBH Thank you very much

Comment: Note that making the data interpolated will not increase the accuracy, as teh data is essentially the same. You could equally just under-sample the input and you will likely get the same result.

Comment: @AnderBiguri you are right, I interpolated the data and the accuracy was very poor! what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Get new data, I guess